# Finding the covariance when given two separate pdf

Tags: probability, covariance

I have two variables which stem from two pdfs

$$f_1(x_1) =\begin{cases} 1/2 + x_1,  & 0\leq x_1 \leq 1\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

and
$$f_2(x_2) =\begin{cases} 1/2 + x_2,  & 0\leq x_2 \leq 1\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$
I'm trying to find the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_2$ in order to fill in the covariance matrix but don't understand how to apply $\operatorname{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = \mathrm{E}(X_1 X_2) - \mathrm{E}(X_1)\mathrm{E}(X_2)$

$\mathrm{E}$ being the expected value

Comment: you need to specify the joint distribution or something more than two individual PDFs to say anything about the covariance of the RVs. Two RVs can have the same PDF, and can have any arbitrary degree of correlation.

Comment: is it safe to say that $X_1$ comes from $f_1$ and $X_2$ comes from $f_2$? (I'm new to this subject and I don't really understand the question itself)

Comment: Not necessarily. Let's think about it like this: Let's say $X_1 = X$ where $X$ is some random variable (let's say $X =1$ if you get heads on a coin flip and $X = -1$ if you get tails). Let's define $X_2 = - X_1 = - X$. Then, $X_1,X_2$ will have the same pdf and have correlation $-1$ (because if you know $X_1$, then you know $X_2 = -X_1$). On the other hand if $X_2 = Y$ where $Y$ is the outcome of another coinflip, then $X_1,X_2$ have the same PDF, but their correlation will be 0, because it's two different (presumably independent) coinflips.

Comment: Does your question say anything about independence?

Comment: yes they do state that the two variables are independent so would this mean that the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_2$ would 0 since there is no correlation?

Comment: Yes - if $X,Y$ are independent then their covariance is $0$. This is because $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$ in this case.

Comment: ohhhhhh. Thank you so much! Now i understand :)